# Replace/display new line from MYSQL to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, replace, newline

I have a big problem displaying line breaks from mysql in my php generated html page.
I tried out `nl2br()`, manual `str_replace()` and so on...
In my sql database the record is like:

```
first line
second line
third line
```

BUT: There are no `\n`'s or `<br>`'s in that record. 
If I get that data via an ajax call and using javascript: `data.mystring.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")` on it, everything works fine!

But now I have to echo that data directly via php. And I don't see any line breaks. NO matter what I try. Any idea?

Here's the script (inserted via an ajax call):

```
$adress = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["adress"]);
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Contact SET Adress = '$adress');
```

Reading the data of the database on my php page:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Contact");
$dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$newString = $dsatz["Adress"];

echo nl2br($newString);
```

Comment: Well if that regex works then there is a `\n` in the database data or maybe its a `\r\n` if you are unixer

Comment: `nl2br()` just works so the problem is in your data/script. Show your script/markup.

Comment: Do you have Notepad++ or and editor that will show newline characters?

Comment: Nope, working on a mac

Comment: "adress" is for speeches. "address" is for locations. Also, @RiggsFolly is probably correct. You may need to `str_replace("\r\n",'<br />', $address)`

Comment: I just found out, that I only get the linbreaks in a textfield with that data.mystring.replace(/\n/g, "<br />") expression.... There are no \n or \r in my database record... :/

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: Are you sure it's `adress` and not `address`? Also check what's actually in that field with `SELECT HEX(x) FROM y` where `x` is the column and `y` is the table. That'll show you the raw values which you can look up on a [chart like this](http://www.asciitable.com).

Answer (score 4):

As no *`\n`* shown in your db you can do

```
UPDATE tab SET yourcommentcolumn= REPLACE(yourcommentcolumn, CHAR(13), '\\n');
```

the `CHAR()` takes an ASCII code for *carrige return* 13 (or you can replace it with *newline* with code 10 if you mean *newline*) and the `\\n` is to escape the \n.

If you manage to replace them, you can then:

```
echo nl2br($yourString)
```

Comment: Best answer as it uses in built functions of MySQL and PHP, though the query can be altered into SELECT REPLACE('columnName', CHAR(13), '\\n') AS 'columnName' FROM 'tableName'; to preserve the original data.

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup over each character and check the value of it with the ord PHP function.

Check the value against an ascii  table and see what value your line separator is.

You can use str_split or access a string like an array in a loop and check each character individually.

ord documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php
chr (contains a link to ascii table) documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php
Strings (String access and modification by character section) documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
And str_split function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Comment: Thanks for that information! That solved the problem as it showed me, that it was an import problem. The imported data had no new lines. Thanks!